# Leaflet divIcon doesn't appear when drawn

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have a sprite sheet with a bunch images of aircraft in various rotations. I'm trying to set my icon to the sprite based on heading. My heading rounding calculation is working and I'm writing the correct class but nothing appears when I draw it. My previous iteration without sprites and just a bunch of separate images and a regular icons worked fine so the drawing portion of the code should be fine. I simply changed the icon type. Any ideas? This is my new marker function

```
 iconClass = '757_' + (Math.round(HDG/15)) * 15
 var nIcon = L.divIcon({className: iconClass});
 marker[i].setIcon(nIcon)
 marker[i].setLatLng(coords);
 marker[i].bindTooltip(CALL);
 mymap.addLayer(marker[i]);
```

my style sheet looks like

```
.757_120{top:0px;left:0px;
width:36px;height:27px;background: url("images/sprites.png") no-repeat -116px -651px;}
.757_135{top:0px;left:0px;
width:33px;height:33px;background: url("images/sprites.png") no-repeat -292px -465px;}
```

loaded like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="images/sprites.css">
```

and

```
console.log(document.styleSheets)
```

seems to show that the style sheet is loaded

Comment: Are you sure that your css is in the folder `images`? `images/sprites.css`

Comment: Yes. sprites.css and sprites.png are both in the images folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out part of my issue was that class names cannot start with a number.